# Problem with getting the select option data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am having problem to get the selected data from a form. Here is my form

```
    <form action="#" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
  <select name="country" id="selectcountries" class="custom-select">
    <option>Select country</option>
    {% for item in countries %}
      <option val="{{ item.name }}"> {{ item.name }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
  </select>   
  <select name ="city" id="selectcities" class="custom-select">
    <option>Select city</option>
  </select>
  <select class="custom-select" name="option" >
    <option selected> Tourist Spot </option>
    <option> Hotel </option>
    <option> Restaurent </option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn tour-btn"><i class="fa fa-search pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="{% url 'advanceSearch' %}"> Search </a></button>
</form>
```

And my views.py is

```
def advanceSearch(request):
    country = request.GET.get('country')
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    option = request.GET.get('option')

    if request.method == "GET" :
        if country:
            message = 'q= %s' % country
        else:
            message = 'Empty'

    else:
        message = 'oops'

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

HTTPResponse always give me empty message even after with passing values by the form. I want to get the data from this form but i cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the scenario with the provided code, and I think your search view is not getting executed. You have provided `{% url 'advanceSearch' %}` in the anchor tag inside button. It should be in the action attribute of the form.

```
<form action="{% url 'advanceSearch' %}" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
  <select name="country" id="selectcountries" class="custom-select">
    <option>Select country</option>
    {% for item in countries %}
      <option val="{{ item.name }}"> {{ item.name }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
  </select>   
  <select name ="city" id="selectcities" class="custom-select">
    <option>Select city</option>
  </select>
  <select class="custom-select" name="option" >
    <option selected> Tourist Spot </option>
    <option> Hotel </option>
    <option> Restaurent </option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn tour-btn"><i class="fa fa-search pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Nalin Dobhal for your replay and its worked.. You saved my day.